# Subdomain for access buckets files

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am trying to create subdomain for my cloud storage. Now, in my site all files hosted in GCS and have url like: http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/@buckletname@/file.jpg

I want create subdomain with name like @buckletname@.site.com. For this, I created the name record in domain zone:

**@buckletname@ IN CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.**

**www.@buckletname@ IN CNAME c.storage.googleapis.com.**

But I can't access files by url @buckletname@.site.com . What am I doing wrong?
Documentation for me is not clear. If you can provide step by step instructions how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the bucket must be the full domain, not simply the name of the subdomain.

For example, if you wanted the domain "myproject.site.com" to be hosted by Google Cloud Storage, the bucket name must be "myproject.site.com", and if you wanted the domain "www.myproject.site.com", you must have a bucket named exactly "www.myproject.site.com."